# Como resolver problema acentuação no Ionic

Tags: angular, angular-routes, ionic4, utf8-decode

Galera, fui passar um dado pelas rotas no Ionic, Angular, só que o o dado é uma string com acento, quando coloco a variável que recebe o valor pra mostrar no titulo ele mostra de boa, contudo, quando entro em outra página e volto ele converte a letra com acentro pra UTF-8 (pelas pesquisas que realizei). Alem disso, tentei com o decode reverter, mas sempre que entra e volta ele converte novamente.

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.inscricao = this.route.params.subscribe(param => {
      this.tituloPesquisa = param['titulo']
    });
    this.listaProdutos = this.gSacola.getProdutos();
  }
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button defaultHref="/"></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>{{ tituloPesquisa }}</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Galera, a solução que encontrei foi no lugar de passar os dados direto na rota utilizar um queryParams; mais informações: https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras